# Swift array as c function buffer

Tags: arrays, swift, unsafemutablepointer

I'm using swift array as output buffer for a function that takes a pointer and fills it, like this:

```
var buffer : [Int32] = ...
tehFillFunc(UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>(buffer))
```

This works fine, the problem is that compiler is complaining that `Variable 'buffer' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant`, which I don't want to do as I'm pretty sure it was mutated in my fill function.

So, is there a way to silence it? (I could just do some dummy set, but I'd prefer to do it properly).

Edit: As requested complete example code that shows the problem (c is not even necessary):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func fill(sth: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>) {
        sth[0] = 7
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var array = [Int32].init(count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)
        fill(UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>(array))
        print("\(array)")
    }
}
```

However, the solution was already posted. In simplest form:

```
        fill(&array)
```

Comment: I do not get any warning with your code ...

Comment: @MartinR You are right, I wonder how the original C function is declared.

Comment: I assumed `void tehFillFunc(int *ptr);`.

Comment: Please update your question with a (small) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: And it seems to be independent on the c/swift as source of the function - just the swift declaration form mattered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you need to have specify buffer size. And in this case I prefer following solution:

```
let bufferSize = 1000
var buffer = [Int32](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
tehFillFunc(&buffer)
```

Comment: Well, this is the closest to what I need. Looks like it was simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method on `Array` for this purpose:

```
var buffer : [Int32] = ...

buffer.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
    tehFillFunc($0.baseAddress)
}
```

I makes sure the array is alive at least until `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` returns. As it takes an `inout` parameter, buffer has to be a `var`.

Comment: That's what I also thought until some time ago, but as I understand https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47085, using withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer is not necessary for a single function invocation: *"Swift guarantees that pointers you generate this way will remain valid for the duration of the function call."*

Comment: @MartinR The good thing about using it that it correctly behaves in the mutating case. If, for example, there's a `didSet` observer on `buffer` it would correctly be called once after `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` returns.

Comment: I see, that is a good point. (But I still wonder where the compiler warning should come from, I cannot reproduce it.)

Comment: @MartinR I was wondering if the function was actually declared `tehFillFunc(const int *ptr);`. Another reason could be an outdated Swift version... But I agree, it would be great if the OP would fill in this missing information.

Comment: In that case the function could not assign new values to the pointed-to elements.

Comment: That actually looks quite awesome in terms of usefulness+safety, but from "didSet will be called after it returns" - looks like there's some internal synchronization going on, which I'd strongly prefer to avoid in this case.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
let buffer = [Int32](unsafeUninitializedCapacity: bufferSize) { buffer, initializedCount in
    tehFillFunc(buffer.baseAddress)
    initializedCount = bufferSize
}
```

Comment: I don't even work on that project anymore, but this looks much better